# PLSQL: Can we run two scheduled job together on same table

Tags: oracle11g

I have a scenario wherein in have to create and run two scheduled jobs almost at the same time. And the code is almost different but only one table(Master_Data1) is in common in select query like below. My main concern is that if this could create any locking conditions. We have to run this code on production and the views have millions of records. Please help me understand if a common table in select accessed by two different sessions can create locks or not.

JOB1:

```
INSERT INTO Result_Table1
SELECT * FROM Master_Data1 md LEFT JOIN vw_External_1 vw;
```

JOB2:

```
INSERT INTO Result_Table2
SELECT * FROM Master_Data1 md LEFT JOIN vw_External_2 vw;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read each row once while multiple processes insert into the same Oracle table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955185/read-each-row-once-while-multiple-processes-insert-into-the-same-oracle-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running only SELECT statement on the Master_Data1 table there should be no locking issues.

For more information on locking and concurrency please read the following Oracle documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT621
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502